# why did I get IllegalThreadStateException after calling this.interrupt()?

Tags: java, concurrency, interrupt

```
try {
    this.interrupt();
} catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I found out that an `IllegalThreadStateException` was thrown by putting print statement, no stack trace was printed. I have tried searching existing threads about Thread.interrupt() and IllegalThreadStateException, but didn't get much out of them. I am using CDLC 1.1, if it helps. thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

CLDC 1.1 is supposed to support `interrupt()`, but CLDC 1.0 didn't. Maybe your particular implementation didn't feel like adding this support, and fakes it by throwing a runtime exception.

Comment: but mine is under CLDC 1.1 for sure. no mistake there.

Answer (score 0):

If no stack trace is printed, it sounds like there error is happening (and being handled) elsewhere.  Can you step through the code in a debugger and see if that interrupt is triggering another thread to have a problem?  It would have to occur with the process of executing `interrupt()`.

In our IDE, I would put a breakpoint on that line, hit F5 to *step inside* the method call, then continue *stepping inside* until I found the problem.  Along the way, if I get to a point where there is no source code I would download the related source jar file and point the debugger to it (which sounds involved but only takes about 2 minutes).

Hope that helps in some way,

-gMale